# Set a 2nd orderby value for a query action?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to order some custom posts by a meta_value, and then secondly order them by the title. How can I set a second orderby value in the below action?

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/jet-smart-filters', function( $query ) {
    
  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'fuel_type_id' );
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
  $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code the set a second order by value in your above action.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/jet-smart-filters', function( $query ) {
    
  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'fuel_type_id' );
  $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value_num', 'title' ) );
  $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

});
```

You can also set the order using **ascending/descending** for each order by value separately by passing in the array. for that, you can show the below example.

```
$query->set( 'orderby', array(
    'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
    'title' => 'DESC'
) );
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Appreciate it!